# ReactJS - CSS: setting trasitionProperty in style object does not work

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I am currently using css transitions based off property updates to handle animations in my react components and all has been working well so far.

The problem I am having now, is that I only need to transition a few of the css properties on one of my components.  Naturally I tried to set the 'transitionProperty' css setting to accomplish this, but for some reason react simply doesn't set this setting!

code example:

```
<div style={{
    color: 'red',
    background-color: 'green',
    transition: 'all 1s ease-out', 
    transitionProperty: 'color, background-color'
}} />
```

The result it gives me is:

```
<div style="color:red; background-color:green; transition:all 1s ease-out" />
```

No 'transition-property'!

I am using ReactJS, with a Webpack build stack and have already tried prefixes like {WebkitTransitionProperty:

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try to use `transitionDuration: '1s', transitionTimingFunction: 'ease-out', transitionProperty: 'color, background-color'`. Could be that `transition` and `transitionProperty` doesn't work together, or perhaps it's because you use `transition: 'all ...'`.

Comment: Also I'm surprised that `background-color` works, it should be `backgroundColor` in React.

Comment: The second code box is the result you get in the browser, therfore: background-color

Comment: Yes, I assumed it was the resulting DOM element. I was referring to the `background-color` inside `style={{...}}`, where it should instead be `backgroundColor` to be a valid JS object property name and conform with React inline style property naming.

Comment: 5 years later...I still encounter this original issue. The accepted answer works but I'd love to know why this doesn't work. Is this a react bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax for transition is:

`transition: <property> || <duration> || <timing-function> || <delay> [, ...];`

so you can write:

```
transition: 'color 1s ease-out, background-color 1s ease-out'
```

---

What's more `transitionProperty` is syntax for JavaScript, for example:

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.transitionProperty = "width,height";
```

In CSS you should use `transition-property` :

```
transition-property: 'color, background-color'
```

Comment: Thanx this solves the issue for me.  But I would still like to know why react is kicking out the 'transition-property' css setting.